# TestCafe: Generate Tests using Data from the Client?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, storybook

Using TestCafe [1], I would like to do the following:

1. Navigate to a URL.
2. Execute Client-Side JavaScript to retrieve a list of other URLs.
3. Generate a test for each URL.
4. Execute the tests **concurrently**.

### Working example which uses a single Test and executes serially

The reduced test case below works but is not quite what I need, it does the following:

1. Execute a test.
2. Navigate to a URL in the "before" hook of the test.
3. Execute Client-Side JavaScript to retrieve a list of URLs in the "before" hook of the test.
4. Run the assertions for each URL **serially** in the body of the test.

My test file run through TestCafe contains this:

```
import { ClientFunction, Selector } from 'testcafe';

const getSiteMapFromClientSide = ClientFunction(
  () =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
      // this example looks like it could be synchronous, or that the data could
      // be defined in the test but this data comes from an async source which
      // is only reachable client side.
      resolve(['https://localhost:6007/some/url1', 'https://localhost:6007/some/url2']);
    })
);

fixture('Storybook').page('https://localhost:6007');

const modalError = Selector('#error-message');

test.before(async t => {
  t.ctx.siteMap = await getSiteMapFromClientSide();
})('Smoke Test all Stories for Full Screen Errors or Blank Screens', async t => {
  // assert we have URLs or we'll have a passing suite that looped over nothing
  await t.expect(t.ctx.siteMap.length > 0).ok('Site Map is Empty');
  // assert each story has no full screen error message
  await Promise.all(
    t.ctx.allStories.map(async url => {
      await t
        .navigateTo(url)
        .expect(modalError.exists && modalError.visible)
        .notOk(`Full Screen Error found at ${url}`);
    })
  );
});
```

### Context

In the real application, I am writing smoke tests for Storybook [2]. To get a list of all URLs I need to call the result
of `require('@storybook/react').getStorybook()`, which is only available in the Storybook Client Application at runtime.
I've left these details out of the reduced test case as they're nothing to with TestCafe.

[1] http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe
[2] https://storybook.js.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to divide your task into two parts.
First, you need to get all tested URLs via ClientFunction and save these URLs somewhere (e.g., to a global variable) using the first test file.
Then start a new TestCafe task with the `concurrency` option and set the `src` param to your second test file.
The best way to do it is to use the `createTestCafe` function. Please also read the following article http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/createtestcafe.html

Comment: how do you save it in global variable in first test file and use that in another ?

Comment: I've added a sample to my answer based on the [Create Helpers](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/extract-reusable-test-code/create-helpers.html) article in your question [How to share a global variable between test files from a test in TestCafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59720665/how-to-share-a-global-variable-between-test-files-from-a-test-in-testcafe)